# Back slash issue while comparing two strings

Tags: iphone, string, backslash

I am  getting some string from service

```
  <iframe width="560" height="314" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/oWeXKVioM34" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I just replaced the string like this

```
  summary = [summary stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"\"" withString:@"\\\""];



    NSString *str2=@"<iframe width=\"560\" height=\"314\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/oWeXKVioM34\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>"// this is my expected string which i got in console area for summary.
```

I am getting exactly in console area but if I compared the strings

```
      if([str2 isEqualToString:summary])
                {
                    NSLog(@"same......");
                }
                else{
                    NSLog(@"notsame ......");
                }
```

I wondered I am getting `notsame` as output even they appear `same` in console area. Then I calculated the length for summary it is 129 and for str2 it is 121.
then I got that there is a problem of backslash because I added 8 slashes,then what to do to get same output.

any help would be really appreciated.
thank you.

Comment: str2 value is my console output of summary

Comment: i think there's an extra \ in \\\", try removing that.

Comment: it i use two it is syntax error,here out of three firsr two is to get single backslash and remaning one is escape character for ".

Comment: Yes you are right I checked my self, consider @leoformaggio's answer, may be that's a help..

Comment: @siva: What exactly you wanted to do ? do you just wanted to load iFrame string into `UIWebView` ?

Comment: @Maulik yes but iam getting  that iframe from service then i converted the string into normal string by using https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser

Comment: @rptwsthi thank you for ur response i just followed leoformaggios answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backslash is used to represent special characters like `"`  on a `NSString` literal. So, actually the `str2` string doesn't have any backslash, while the `summary` string do (added by `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:`).

Comment: then what can i do to get the same sting  as str2 from my original string and i want to use tht string to play video in webview

Comment: To load this HTML string on an `UIWebView` for example, you don't need to do a `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:` on `summary`. Just do this `[webView loadHTMLString:summary baseURL:nil]`.

Comment: then iam not getting video it is just showing my total string in my webview

Comment: Try doing this `summary = [summary stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\\"" withString:@"\""];`.

Comment: thanks finally i got it by directly loading my webview [webView loadHTMLString:summary baseURL:nil] like this from last few days i was doing like  summary =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\
                                     <html>\
                                     <head>\
                                     <body>\
                                     %@\
                                     </body>\
                                     </html>", summary];

Comment: great thx. i have one small doubt in my web view i may get content or video(any type) or both then how can i proceed to load both my content and video

Comment: if my video is flash then how to proceed, because the flash videos are not supported in ios

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer! If summary contains all the HTML stuffs (text and/or video), it should work without any changes. In the flash case, I suggest you to add an `UILabel` notifying the user that the video is *Unavailable on this platform*, or something like that.

Comment: If you wanna know how to check if a given HTML string contains a flash video, you can search for the *.swf* substring.

Comment: if .swf is there means  is it  of type flash ?

Comment: The short answer is yes, but in a more robust way you should parse the HTML. I was thinking about it, and the most elegant way is to setting the `UIWebView` delegate and implement the `webView:didFailLoadWithError:` method, which will be called if something goes wrong, like trying to load a HTML with Flash content.